# Modify tf.keras.metrics.MeanRelativeError

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I want to use tf.keras.metrics.MeanRelativeError to implement the calculation of residual per unit observation, which is defined as abs(y_true - y_pred) / y_true. However, I found that I cannot set the normalizer to y_true when using tf.keras.metrics.MeanRelativeError. Therefore, I decided to copy the source code of tf.keras.metrics.MeanRelativeError, make some modifications to it, and create a custom metric named ResidualPerUnitObservation. Here are the modifications I made:

```py
class ResidualPerUnitObservation(base_metric.Mean):
    @dtensor_utils.inject_mesh  # DTensor, Mesh, and Layout: https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/dtensor_overview
    def __init__(self, normalizer=None, name=None, dtype=None):
        super().__init__(name=name, dtype=dtype)
        if normalizer is not None:
            normalizer = tf.cast(normalizer, self._dtype)
        self.normalizer = normalizer

    def update_state(self, y_true, y_pred, sample_weight=None):
        """Accumulates metric statistics.

        Args:
          y_true: The ground truth values.
          y_pred: The predicted values.
          sample_weight: Optional weighting of each example. Defaults to 1. Can
            be a `Tensor` whose rank is either 0, or the same rank as `y_true`,
            and must be broadcastable to `y_true`.

        Returns:
          Update op.
        """
        y_true = tf.cast(y_true, self._dtype)
        y_pred = tf.cast(y_pred, self._dtype)
        # ragged_tensor: https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/ragged_tensor
        [
            y_pred,
            y_true,
        ], sample_weight = metrics_utils.ragged_assert_compatible_and_get_flat_values(  # noqa: E501
            [y_pred, y_true], sample_weight
        )
        y_pred, y_true = losses_utils.squeeze_or_expand_dimensions(
            y_pred, y_true
        )
        if self.normalizer is None:
            self.normalizer = y_true
        y_pred, self.normalizer = losses_utils.remove_squeezable_dimensions(
            y_pred, self.normalizer
        )
        y_pred.shape.assert_is_compatible_with(y_true.shape)
        relative_errors = tf.math.divide_no_nan(
            tf.abs(y_true - y_pred), self.normalizer
        )

        return super().update_state(
            relative_errors, sample_weight=sample_weight
        )

    def get_config(self):
        n = self.normalizer
        config = {
            "normalizer": backend.eval(n) if is_tensor_or_variable(n) else n
        }
        base_config = super().get_config()
        return dict(list(base_config.items()) + list(config.items()))
```

However, when I specify metrics as ResidualPerUnitObservation() in model.compile and execute model.fit, I encounter an error message:

`"The tensor <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:1' shape=(None, 1) dtype=float32> cannot be accessed from here, because it was defined in FuncGraph(name=train_function, id=2877768837632), which is out of scope."`

Can anyone help me solve this problem? Thank you in advance for your help.